# How can I combine multiple rows of a table into multiple columns in Mysql with 1 query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores values based on two identifying values (product code, and a detail code) that make each row unique and a 3rd value that stores a type of value based on the detail code.  What I would like to do is display all of the third values for any one product code in new columns.  The detail code would act as a column header.

What I have tried so far:

```
SELECT id1, 
CASE WHEN id2 ='A'
THEN value
ELSE 0 
END A, 
CASE WHEN id2 ='B'
THEN value
ELSE 0 
END B
FROM table1
WHERE id2 = 'A' OR id2 = 'B'
GROUP BY id1
```

This has worked ok, except that when a value for id2 = 'A' exists inn the table, the CASE WHEN for id2 = 'B' defaults to 0 instead of the correct value, if there is one.  If there is no record for the id2 = 'A' then the CASE WHEN will work correctly for id2 = 'B'.

I'm assuming there's also a better way to go about this, but had trouble finding this exact situation anywhere.  I can definitely use the data without the multiple columns, but was hoping not to/learn something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query formatted so I can read it:

```
SELECT id1, 
       (CASE WHEN id2 = 'A' THEN value
             ELSE 0 
        END) as A, 
       (CASE WHEN id2 = 'B' THEN value
             ELSE 0 
        END) as B
FROM table1
WHERE id2 in ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY id1;
```

What I notice is that you have the `id2` field in the `select` with no aggregation function.  You seem to want the value when one or the other occurs.  Try this:

```
SELECT id1, 
       max(CASE WHEN id2 = 'A' THEN value
                ELSE 0 
           END) as A, 
       max(CASE WHEN id2 = 'B' THEN value
                ELSE 0 
           END) as B
FROM table1
WHERE id2 in ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY id1;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect!  Any chance you could explain why the Max function lets this work?  I had gotten the query to work, except for that if there was a value for id2 = A and id2 = B, that the value for B wasn't getting pulled.

Comment: @theisenm85 . . . The problem is that MySQL chooses arbitrary values for `value` and `id2` because you are aggregating by another field.  This is a common source of confusion for users of MySQL.  My advice is to follow ANSI rules, so every column not in the `group by` should be wrapped in an aggregation function (such as `max()`).